# Not able to write in file - JAVA Servlets

Tags: java, file, servlets, printwriter

I am trying to write into a file in Java Servlets. I have the same code in a normal java project and it works fine but it does not in Java Servlet.

Please refer to the code below for the class which contains the method:

```
public class UserRecords {

    private String fileName = "Users.txt";

    public void addRecord(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String pass){

        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

            pw.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + email + " " + pass);

            fw.flush();
            fw.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserRecords.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Java Servlet which calls the method:

```
public class Register extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

        UserRecords ur = new UserRecords();

//        ur.addRecord(firstName, lastName, email, pass);
          ur.addRecord("Bucky", "Roberts", "bucky@records.com", "mypass");

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("firstName", firstName);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/welcome.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);


    }

}
```

Please help and guide to write to the file Users.txt

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *in a normal java project and it works fine but it does not in Java Servlet.*, does not describes the issue, kindly elaborate the issue in detail. Did you checked the path if file is created or blank files gets created or there are any logs captured with respect to error encountered, if any.

Comment: Can you confirm if the method is getting called? Or is there some exception before the method gets called?

Comment: @Arvind I have tested the same code in a regular java project and it creates the file and prints to it but it does not do the same here. Even the file is not created. I also tried creating the file in the root to test if it could just print at least but it does not do anything.

Comment: Try more logs on server tracing file absolute path, premission(read/write) using `File` class.

Comment: @NicholasK There are no exceptions and the method is also called as I have put an System.out in the method to verify.

Comment: Are you running this from an IDE like eclipse on your local or is your web-app hosted somewhere?

Comment: @NicholasK I am using NetBeans.

Comment: Can you search your work-space once with the file `Users.txt`? If there are no exceptions as per your comments, it should be created somewhere. Search via your IDE as well as from your local directory structure.

Comment: @NicholasK I did a search on my workspace and found it in a weird location which was in C:\Users\sufiyaan\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\config. Also, it did not write anything to it.

Comment: The issue got resolved when I put the complete file path i.e. C:/Users/sufiyaan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Exotica Travels/Users.txt in the parameter. However, is there a way if I can get this done without putting the complete path or a method where it can automatically get the path and then create the file?

Comment: Told you the file was somewhere. You will need to define the path or ideally define it in a property file so that it can change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to work reliably in servlet environments, you need to understand some more things about the environment in which your stuff is going to be running.

One, your servlet might be deployed to several distinct servlet containers running on the same machine simultaneously.  Think a test machine dedicated to the purpose of testing whether it runs on Tomcat as well as Glassfish as well as Websphere as well as ..., or Tomcat 7 as well as Tomcat 8 as well as Tomcat 9.  Each of those should then be getting their own users.txt file and each should be insulated from the users.txt of any of the others.  There is no elegant way to get out of this but to have your file path in ${user.home} and then hope that, say the three tomcat instances, are not running under the same userid.

Then, within a given servlet container, your servlet might get deployed to more than one distinct virtual host.  So you need to obtain the virtual-host name from your environment and include that in the full file path (there is a call in java EE to do that but I don't know by heart which one that is).

Then, within a given virtual host, your servlet might have gotten included in more than one distinct application (/context) and you need to make sure each instance is insulated from the instances of the other applications (/contexts) it is included in.  So you need to obtain the application (/context) name from your environment and include that in the full file path.

And finally, doing those calls in a non-EE environment ("in a normal java project") is obviously going to produce crashes at best and the very same problem of "where has the file gone" at worst.

EDIT for additional clarification :

where I said "you need to ensure ... insulated" I meant more of "you need to think it through and determine whether you want insulation or sharing at that level".  If you do want sharing, the consequence is that you must make sure your data management is given all the usual ACID properties just like any other DBMS engine you would/could be using.